# Table Splitting / Optional Relationship

Tags: entity-framework

Currently, I have the following in my code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasRequired(e => e.Logo).WithRequiredPrincipal();
```

This relationship definition is used for table splitting the Logo column (which is VARBINARY(MAX)) into a separate entity.  Everything works as expected.

I have chosen to make the Logo column nullable in the database.  I tried updating the code listed above to:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasOptional(e => e.Logo).WithOptionalPrincipal();
```

When I run the code, I receive the following message:

Additional information: The entity types 'ClientLogo' and 'Client' cannot share table 'clients' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them.

The problem is that I am not entirely sure what this message is trying to tell me.  Why does it work when the Logo column is non-nullable but does not work when it is not?  Am I mapping the relationship incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the `Logo` column is optional, the entity relationship between `ClientLogo` and `Client` needs to remain the same, it's the property itself that needs to be nullable:

```
// This should stay the same
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasRequired(e => e.Logo).WithRequiredPrincipal();

// If you used to have a line like this or a [Required] attribute, then it needs to be removed
// modelBuilder.Entity<ClientLogo>().Property(t => t.Logo).IsRequired();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I must say that your solution still leaves me a bit confused.  Establishing relationships in EF is still a bit of a mystery to me.  I think what is throwing me off is that for these types of relationships (table splitting) the value of the property (Logo in this case) cannot be null, even if the end column is not required.  Anyhow, I marked your solution as the answer as it got my code working.

Comment: @JasonRichmeier: I think it might make more sense if you imagine the implications in the case where `ClientLogo` has more than just one property, but `ClientLogo` wasn't required. There would be more edge cases to handle when going between the entity model and the database representation.